# AngularJS $http.get returns undefined

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs

I'm building a small angular application. I've started from here: https://github.com/angular/angular-seed. I've changed only the following files:

1. /app/view1/view1.js
       'use strict';

   ```
   angular.module('myApp.view1', ['ngRoute'])

   .config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {
     $routeProvider.when('/view1', {
       templateUrl: 'view1/view1.html',
       controller: 'View1Ctrl'
     });
   }])


   .controller('View1Ctrl', ['$scope', '$http',
     function ($scope, $http) {
       $http.get('/app/data/events.json').success(function(data) {
         $scope.events = data.record;
       }).error(function(data, status){
           alert("error "+data+' | '+status);
       });

       $scope.orderProp = 'date';
     }]);
   ```
2. /app/view1/view1.html

   ```
   p>Available Events</p>

   <div ng-controller="EventListController">
     <ul>
       <li ng-repeat="event in events">
           <p>{{event.name}}</p>
           <div>{{event.location}}</div>
           <div>{{event.description}}</div>
           <div>{{event.date}}</div>

       </li>

     </ul>

    <p>Total number of events: {{events.size}}</p>
   </div>
   ```

When the page is displayed I get the following message:

> "error undefined | undefined".

I've checked the code several times and I did not find why the json file is not loaded. If I try to access http://localhost:8000/app/data/events.json in browser the json data is loaded.

The question is: why json file is not loaded?

Comment: open console (F12) and check, I think problem is in your 'localhost'.
Set some domain name and try again.

Comment: Option+Command+J on a Mac

Comment: try removing the app from your url and type it like this /data/events.json

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use $http methods like below:

```
// Simple GET request example:
$http.get('url').then(function successCallback(response) {
    // this callback will be called asynchronously
    // when the response is available
  }, function errorCallback(response) {
    // called asynchronously if an error occurs
    // or server returns response with an error status.
  });
```

Variables in your code `data` and `status` are undefined.

You should update your code like this:

```
 $http.get('/app/data/events.json')
 .then(function successCallback(response) {
      $scope.events = data.record;
  },
  function errorCallback(response) {
      alert(response);
  });
```

It's will be solve your problem.